# how to prove transitivity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm never really sure how to prove transitivity when it comes to relations.  I know how to disprove transitivity, by simply providing a counter example.

For example, in this problem, I have to prove whether or not this relation is reflexive, symmetric/anti-symmetric, and transitive.  The relation is defined as the relation $R$ on $\Bbb R$ (real numbers) where $aRb$ means $a = 1/b$ is an element of $\Bbb Z$ (integers).

I proved it was reflexive and that it was symmetric, but I don't know how to prove if this is transitive or not.

I also can't seem to find a counter example where it isn't transitive.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $x\,R\,y$ and $y\,R\,z$. Then $x-y\in\Bbb Z$ and $y-z\in\Bbb Z$, and we want to show that $x-z\in\Bbb Z$. How might we get $x-z$ from $x-y$ and $y-z$? A little thought shows that we can add them: $x-z=(x-y)+(y-z)$, and the sum of two integers is an integer, so $x-z\in\Bbb Z$, and $x\,R\,z$. This shows that $R$ is transitive.

**Added 22 February 2023:** Please note that this is an answer to the question as it was originally asked: in that version $a\mathrel{R}b$ was defined to mean that $a-b\in\Bbb Z$. The $R$ of the current version is also transitive, but the argument is completely different.

Suppose that $x,y,z\in\Bbb R$, $x\mathrel{R}y$, and $y\mathrel{R}z$; then $x=\frac1y\in\Bbb Z$, and $y=\frac1z\in\Bbb Z$. In particular, both $y$ and $\frac1y$ are integers, so either $y=1$ or $y=-1$. In either case $y=\frac1y$, so $x=y=\frac1z$, $x\mathrel{R}z$, and $R$ is transitive.

That is, we have both $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\mathrel{R}z$ **only** when $x=y=z=1$ or $x=y=z=-1$, so those are the only cases in which we actually have to check transitivity. And in both of those cases we do have $x\mathrel{R}z$, so $R$ is transitive.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thank you.  But in general, how do you go about proving transitivity.  Because every 3 elements in a set need to be transitive, it is easy to prove when it isn't.  But every source I look at seems to use a different method for each problem when proving transitivity

Comment: Every source should start the proof the same way: supposing that $x\,R\,y$ and $y\,R\,z$. But then you have to use the definition of the relation to show that those imply $x\,R\,z$, and that will be different for each problem.

Comment: @wcr221: I’m afraid that it’s always going to depend on the specific relation involved; there really isn’t a general rule, though it usually isn’t **too** hard for the relations that you’re likely to encounter in a typical sophomore-level discrete math course. But what Joe says in the previous comment is exactly right.

Comment: how did we arrive at $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y-z \in \mathbb{Z}$? I do not see this in the description for $R$. Is there some definition I am missing?

Comment: @DavidT: My answer applies to the original version of the question, in which $a\mathrel{R}b$ was defined to mean that $a-b\in\Bbb Z$; you can see it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3629346/revisions). I see now that this was completely changed in the $3:50$ edit, which I never saw. When I have a few minutes, I’ll add something to the answer to explain what happened and address the revised version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I also can't seem to find a counter example where it isn't transitive.

Indeed.

You prove transitivity by showing, for *any* $a,b,c$ in the domain, that $a\operatorname Rb$ and $b\operatorname Rc$ *must* entail that $a\operatorname Rc$.   That involves proving that a counter example **cannot** exist, either directly or indirectly (ie by a conditional proof, or a proof by reduction to absurdity).

---

- Begin with the definition for $\operatorname R$ as $\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2: x-y\in\Bbb Z\}$

  - Assume, for *arbitrary real* values $a,b,c$, that $a\operatorname R b\wedge b\operatorname Rc$.
  - This assumption entails $a-b\in\Bbb Z$ and $b-c\in\Bbb Z$ by the definition.
  - That entails $(a-b)+(b-c)$ is the sum of two integers.
  - Of course $a-c=(a-b)+(b-c)$ by algebra.
  - Thus entailing that $a-c\in\Bbb Z$ by the additive closure of the integers.
  - Thus entailing that $a\operatorname R c$ by the definition for $\operatorname R$.
- Therefore $\forall a{\in}\Bbb R~\forall b{\in}\Bbb R~\forall c{\in}\Bbb R~(a\operatorname R b\wedge b\operatorname R c\to a\operatorname R c)$.
- Done.   Our $\operatorname R$ is transitive.